# Trying to install PyAudio on OS X ( 10.11.3)

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew, pyaudio

I used brew to install port audio.
I then tried pip install pyaudio.

I get:

error: $MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET mismatch: now "10.9" but "10.11" during configure

How can I set the MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET so that I don't get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='desired value'` in Terminal just before you run the installation process.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to install the [sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.rtfd.org/) module instead of PyAudio:

```
pip install sounddevice
```

UPDATE: To install it as a user (without needing `sudo`), use:

```
pip install sounddevice --user
```

Comment: Similar error: 
sudo pip install sounddevice
Password:
Downloading/unpacking sounddevice
  Downloading sounddevice-0.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Downloading/unpacking CFFI (from sounddevice)
  Downloading cffi-1.5.2.tar.gz (388kB): 388kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/tmp/pip_build_root/CFFI/setup.py) egg_info for package CFFI
    <built-in>:0: error: Unknown value ‘10.11’ of -mmacosx-version-min
    _configtest.c:1: error: thread-local storage not supported for this target

Comment: Hmmm ... probably the compiler you are using is too old ... can you upgrade it?

Comment: You could also try to install the [requirements](http://python-sounddevice.rtfd.org/#requirements) with your package manager (homebrew/MacPorts/...). The `sounddevice` module itself doesn't need any compilation.